# How to pass a selected object to a Controller using Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core, razor

I'm currently trying to pass a object called DropDown from a View to a controller action using HTML.DropDownFor() and a form.

The object looks like this:

```
public class DropDown
   {
       public int id { get; set; }

       public string value { get; set; }
   }
```

The view Model looks like this:

```
    public class GraphViewModel
    {
        public DropDown SelectedGraphTypeDropDown { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<DropDown> GraphTypeDropDowns { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller action looks like this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public string GetTestData(DropDown SelectedGraphTypeDropDown)
        {
            // use above object here
        }
```

And the view like so:

```
            @using (Html.BeginForm("GetTestData", "Graph", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedGraphTypeDropDown, new SelectList(Model.GraphTypeDropDowns, "id", "value"))
                <input type="submit" />
            }
```

[Rendered HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF2XO.png)

What I expect to happen is the selected GraphType will be passed to the GetTestData action and resolved as a whole object called "SelectedGraphTypeDropDown".
I have debugged through it and it seems that the selected GraphType id (int) is passed to the controller but the whole object is not. I have also tried to pass each field of the selectedGraphTypeDropDown but this wont work as the fields are set after the page is rendered.

Also is there a way to pass the full viewModel to the controller?

Any advice would be apricated thanks!

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like for this form?

Comment: @Jasen Ive added a screenshot of the rendered HTML above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,dropdown cannot pass a model,but you can add hidden input to bind value.Here is a demo:

view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetTestData", "Graph", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedGraphTypeDropDown.id, new SelectList(Model.GraphTypeDropDowns, "id", "value"))
    <input id="value" name="SelectedGraphTypeDropDown.value" hidden/>
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

js(js will bind selected value to hidden input):

```
$(function () {
        $("#value").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    })
    $("#SelectedGraphTypeDropDown_id").change(function () {
        $("#value").val($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    })
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you I like this solution